# Rope in cocos2d & box2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

all! I'm creating a game based on Box2d and Cocos2d. I want to make up a rope, which will be able to contact with all of the physical objects. Something like this:

http://rghost.ru/35987917.view

I created a rope by using a rectangles joined through a revolute joint, but creating more than 3 ropes reduces fps from 60 down to 30. I must use at least 5 ropes, water and particles in Cocos2d, but in this way fps will be near 5-10, how to avoid this?

Comment: Quick clarification. Is your low fps rate on your actual device or is it in the simulator? Tassinari is correct in that a b2RopeJoint won't solve what you are trying to do since it is not a Rigid Body.

Comment: I know about b2RopeJoint, it's my plan "B"=) But I really need rope which contacting with all physical objects

Answer (score 2):

Use a box2d rope joint and verlet rope from this tutorial:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/1112

There shouldn't be any performance issues with 5 ropes with this method.
You may have to update your box2d version though because b2RopeJoint is relatively new.

Comment: Sorry just saw the image again, the problem with the vrope is it has no presence in the world and would not hang on the circle in the picture as it is presently.

Comment: link is broken at the moment?